# Can timeless entities have properties that vary with time?

Tags: time, abstract

Can abstract and timeless entities, like natural numbers and sets, have properties that vary with time? I am inclined to think they do. For example, the largest known prime number keeps changing with time. However, it seems a little weird to me for timeless entities to have properties that vary with time. So, what is the truth of the matter?

Comment: There's this phrase "Cambridge change" that applies, except that the kind of property-change is not a "real change" (I think scholastic theologians spoke in such terms betimes, saying that God Itself doesn't change when relations to It change). [Alexander Pruss](http://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2016/09/contingent-sets.html) discusses contingent, but pure, sets (I think his extended thesis involves epistemic relations); c.f. Linsky and Zalta's defense of [contingently nonconcrete objects](https://mally.stanford.edu/Papers/tomberlin.pdf).

Comment: Do properties inhere in an object or in the models we use to describe an object?

Comment: Why not? What seems to be the difficulty here?

Comment: Philosophers distinguish [intrinsic properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intrinsic-extrinsic/), that entities have as such, and extrinsic properties, that are dependent on their relations to other entities. Timeless entities can have only timeless intrinsic properties, but "being the largest known prime" is extrinsic.  It is not so much a property of a prime as of its relation to temporal human knowledge. It is not surprising that relations to temporal entities vary with time, as long as the variance is entirely due to temporal relata, as in this case.

Comment: Essentially it’s your same accepted answer as only a few days ago you asked about dispositional properties such as abilities which is subtly different from the same said subject’s categorical properties…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the properties of the entities per se, which do not change with time, with the relationships between the entities and humans, which do change with time. You might say that the number 19, for example, has the property of being the subject of your thought, since my mentioning it has caused you to think about it; however, that is just a manner of speaking- it is not an inherent property of the number 19. Likewise when you refer to the largest known prime, you are really referring to the state of human knowledge of prime numbers. So there are two uses of the word 'property'. One refers to the inherent qualities of an abstract entity which do not change with time, while the other relates to qualities we humans attribute to them that do change with time.